# Is there any way to automatically close a folder in Windows after I open a shortcut?

Tags: windows-7

So, I use this folder taskbar "pinning" app which, when I open the folders icon from the taskbar, will run an instance of Windows Explorer for that specific folder. One of those folders I pinned is where I keep most of the app shortcuts I don't want to have on my taskbar, so I would like that, when I run one of those shortcuts, the folder would automatically close.

Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so.  If you want to write your own code, you could either make a launcher app or abuse jump lists.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and perhaps better.

1. Right-click the Taskbar
2. Select Toolbars
3. Then Select "New Toolbar"
4. Select the folder with all of your shortcuts

This way, you simply access your folder full of Shortcuts using an added Toolbar.  The toolbar is on the Taskbar and is only as wide as the name of the folder with your shortcuts.  I use "_H" as the name of my folder full of shortcuts.

This works in Windows XP, Vista, 7.  I have not tried it in 8.

-- Patrick B.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I had a similar problem, and I found a program that helped so much. MadAppLauncher that allow you to define your own shortcuts and onen tons of programs without using the mouse, with 3 keys.
https://sites.google.com/site/madapplauncher/

I'm now involved in that software, I just find it so useful.